# Xamarin Studio: Does not display the list for to create C# Android project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am try use Xamarin Studio for Android. But, when i click **File->New->Project...** i don't see **C#: Android application**.
[image]

How to fix it? Thanks!!

Comment: Look in your IDE log for a hint (Help - Open Log Directory). The Android addin may be disabled although usually it is because the Xamarin.Android SDK is not installed. This is not the same as the Android SDK.

Comment: @MattWard, i find logs and i see next line: [2016-06-16 02:18:51.8] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.
[2016-06-16 02:18:51.8] INFO: sdk:   Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.
[2016-06-16 02:18:51.8] INFO: Did not find Xamarin.Android
[2016-06-16 02:18:51.8] INFO: Found Android SDK. API levels: (none)

Comment: The "Did not find Xamarin.Android" is the reason you are not seeing any Android project templates. I would try repairing Xamarin from Control Panel. That should install Xamarin.Android.

Comment: @jzeferino - I did not ask any question :) Also I do not believe installing the MSBuild tools will fix it but it is worth a try. The MSBuild tools are used by Xamarin Studio not by Xamarin.Android.

Comment: @MattWard, where can i download Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Xamarin.Android is included in Xamarin's universal installer but it is also included in the Xamarin.VisualStudio.msi (note that even though it says Visual Studio it does not require it to be installed). These are available from your [account page](https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said [here](https://releases.xamarin.com/category/xamarin-studio/): The Cycle 7 version of *Xamarin Studio on Windows* *requires* both *Microsoft Build Tools 2013* (or Visual Studio 2013) and *Microsoft Build Tools 2015* (or Visual Studio 2015) to be installed.
You will need to update yours.

As a personal suggestion. Since you are using Windows I recommend to use [Visual Studio Community](http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.1.0.530.msi). Its free and recommended by Xamarin.

To complement the answer I will quote what @MattWard said in the comments:

> Xamarin.Android is included in Xamarin's universal installer but it is
>   also included in the Xamarin.VisualStudio.msi (note that even though
>   it says Visual Studio it does not require it to be installed). These
>   are available from your [account page](https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads)

Comment: @Tomas did you tried to download and fresh install the visual studio community?

Comment: Yes! It solved my problem, but @MattWard was right too. Thank you))

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Android SDK?

Comment: I was reinstaled it for 3 times. But i don't have Visual Studio. Maybe is it source of problem?